# Code to determine WP version check

Tags: theme-development

I'm unable to devine what's causing my theme to crash in WP 2.9.2, although I know its something in my query statement below, so I need to do a version check for (version) < 3 to branch it.

What is the method to get the currently installed WP version? - I'm just using "wp_version" as a stand in :)

```
if(wp_version < 3)
    $myqueryTopMenu = '';
else
    $myqueryTopMenu = new WP_Query();$myqueryTopMenu->query(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'post_not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts')));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_bloginfo( 'version' )`

Other version globals can be found in wp-includes/version.php

Also, it's safer to use PHP's [version_compare()](http://php.net/version_compare).

Comment: Found out a better way. See updated answer.